# How can I extend the length of an array by 1 in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I want an array capacity to increase as I add items in order to add as many items to it as possible. Is there a way to do this in C#?

Comment: Check out [`List<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8)s.

Comment: Or you could do an ArrayList();

Answer (score 7):

In C#, arrays are fixed lenght. The only way would be to create a new array, copy the contents and add the data.

Or just use `List<T>` or any other self-growing collection instead. They deal with exactly that part of the plumbing.

Comment: Couldn't hey us an ArrayList as well? That way they could consistently change the capacity of the collection?

Comment: @RookTKO Yes and No. ArrayList is the pre-generics List. All that pre-generic stuff should be quietly burried and forgotten. If you want to get rid of type safety, you can always use `List<Object>` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist#remarks

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```
Array.Resize(ref YourArray, i + 1);
```

Comment: Maybe, but this actually allocates a new array; that should be made clear in your answer.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Do you have a solution that _doesn't_?

Comment: @DStanley No, where did I imply that I did? Someone may see this and think an existing array is being resized; it isn't. I'm not suggesting it won't be satisfactory for the OP.